# How to make a background stable and responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_bw_portfolio.htm
I want to build a website like this. I don't how to make a picture stable and responsive like the picture of lady on the left. This web templates is from w3schools.com, but I cant find the stylesheet. I have done the right side, and make mine look like the right side of templates. but I don't know how to set up a picture like the left side of the template. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

the image is wrapped in a nav element with `style: width=40%`.
the div element containing the content has a left margin of 40%.

```
.bgimg {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(/w3images/profile_girl.jpg);
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

The `nav` element, the image is wrapped into should have the following css class:

```
.w3-sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed!important;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

that should do the trick.

Comment: Hi, Ralph. Can u take a look at my code? i just updated it. when I add the code you did on mine, the background image doesnt appear. I have to set up a height in pixel. do you know how to fix this ?